# Showing information about databases in ado.net

Tags: c#, ado.net, sql-server-2008-r2

How can I see all databases in curent connection using ado.net? And then see all tables in each database.

Comment: thank you all for help. But i have some problems with connecting sql server. I get these errors: http://pastebin.com/Mr4SF0a0 using these code: http://pastebin.com/VSxXrwk5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[it gets all database](http://en.csharp-online.net/List_SQL_Server_databases)

[it gets all tables from database](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/01/31/2781.aspx)(this link was deleted now use this one. but change code little)

[ADO.Net : Get table definition from SQL server tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457485/ado-net-get-table-definition-from-sql-server-tables)

you can iterate over database and get all tables

Comment: @AEMLoviji thank you  for help. But i have some problems with connecting sql server. I get these errors: http://pastebin.com/Mr4SF0a0 using these code: http://pastebin.com/VSxXrwk5

Comment: USE IT PLEASE Data Source=.;Integrated Security=True

Comment: @AEMLoviji: i use what you say, but also get these errors: http://pastebin.com/Pq6xycps

Comment: maybe it is for that I have 2 sql servers?

Comment: no i tested it it works. maybe you are using sqlexpress? my connectionstring is   String conxString = @"Data Source=.\sqlexpress; Integrated Security=True;"; because i am using express edition of sqlserver

Comment: yes if you want to get correct connection string use ServerExplorer from visual studio after connect. check it is property and copy connectionstring property. it will really work. :-)

Comment: @AEMLoviji  : yes it works. It was because sqlexpress. Thank you very much!)

Comment: Can I email you if I have some questions? And do you speak Russian?

Comment: yes i can speak in Russian. But you can give your question here. I am not the best here. maybe another people can help you best me

Comment: @AEMLoviji Просто я непонимаю почему твой код работает правильно. Ведь table это же таблица, а row строка таблицы, почему он вовзращает Databases?

Comment: please speak in English here. You can see that we have not set initial catalog property of connection string so sqlConx.GetSchema("Databases"); get all database names from your sql server. if you will add initial catalog property to connection string.  and change sqlConx.GetSchema("Databases") to sqlConx.GetSchema("Tables") it will get all tables from given database. you can test it will understand how it works.

Comment: Ok, I understand you. But how can I get tables names. Where row is database you wrote row["database_name"], but when row is table and I write  row["table_name"] i get error.

Comment: String conxString = @"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=testForAvR; Integrated Security=True;";
            using (SqlConnection sqlConx = new SqlConnection(conxString))
            {
                sqlConx.Open();
                DataTable tblDatabases = sqlConx.GetSchema("Tables");
                sqlConx.Close();

                foreach (DataRow row in tblDatabases.Rows)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("table: " + row["table_name"]);
                }
            }   it works for me. because i have added Initial Catalog=testForAvR to connection string

Comment: your algorithm is not correct. first you will get database and then write second loop and get table from current item

Comment: the second link no longer works...Could you please update that link?

Answer (score 5):

To list all databases you need to specify connection string without initial database. Then you can execute "[sp_databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176070.aspx)" stored procedure.

To list all tables in database you need to query [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186224.aspx).

**SAMPLES**

To get databases:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection SqlCon = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("server=192.168.0.1;uid=sa;pwd=1234");
SqlCon.Open();
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand SqlCom = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
SqlCom.Connection = SqlCon;
SqlCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlCom.CommandText = "sp_databases";

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader SqlDR;
SqlDR = SqlCom.ExecuteReader();

while(SqlDR.Read())
{
   Console.WriteLine(SqlDR.GetString(0));
}
```

To get tables:

```
string connectionString = "...";
DataTable tables = new DataTable("Tables");
using (SqlConnection connection =
       new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "select table_name as Name from
              INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables where TABLE_TYPE =
              'BASE TABLE'";
    connection.Open();
    tables.Load(command.ExecuteReader(
                    CommandBehavior.CloseConnection));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In visual Studio 2010

Select View => Server Explorer

Then write server name, if you use SQL Server Authentication, select it, write your user name and password, select or enter a database name => OK

In the Server Explorer under the Data Connections you will see your database and tables.

Comment: yes it will show database and tables on it. but where is ADO.NET?