# How to check if Field can contain NULL (adFldIsNullable)

Tags: mysql, vbscript, asp-classic, ado

I have tried this code (ASP CLASSIC):

```
Public Function IsNullable(MyField)
    Dim RS, SQL, Tmp
    SQL = "SELECT " & MyField & " FROM mytable WHERE 1;"
    Set RS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    RS.Open SQL, conn 'I have connection opened elsewhere, using Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2w Driver}

    'Now check for Attributes
    Tmp = RS.Fields(MyField).Attributes
    IsNullable = 0 <> (Tmp And adFldIsNullable) '0x20
    RS.Close
    Set RS = Nothing
End Function
```

Function works fine but sometimes the result is wrong. For example it returns True for ID field, which is definitely not nullable as it is Primary Index Autoincrement. How can I make it relable?? Thanks

Added: It seems like when column is set to AutoIncrement Not Null then function works wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's by design according to http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=3857

> [21 Jul 2004 22:26] Timothy Smith (Senior Support Engineer in those days)
>
> This is because MySQL reports the DEFAULT value for such a column as NULL.  It means, if you
> insert a NULL value into the column, you will get the next integer value for the table's 
> auto_increment counter.

It is still valid and @kordirko's solution is quite acceptable.

Comment: That't exactly what I was looking for. I cannot vote as I'm greenhorn here. I can live without checking ID column... Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In MySql you can query `information_schema.columns` view:

```
SELECT is_nullable
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'my_schema'
  AND table_name   = 'table-name'
  AND column_name = 'column name'
```

see this demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/743d6/3

Comment: I'm pretty sure this method will work, thanks. But what if I can't / don't want to use information_schema?

Comment: Information_schema is ANSI standard --> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema, many databases implement it, so it's the easiest method to query database metadata. If you don't like it, well, I really don't know the other way. Mayby dig into ADO.NET documentation, I don't know ADO.NET and I can't help, but I am pretty sure they have some functions to query table metadata, for example I've found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457485/ado-net-get-table-definition-from-sql-server-tables